# Using an Internal HDD as an External HDD also or an External HDD for installing SAP?

Tags: windows, performance, sap

Is it possible and advisable to use an Internal Hard Drive as an External Hard drive also.

I wanted to install SAP ECC 6 on my system which has only 250 GB but atleast 300 GB is required.I wanted to buy an External Drive first, then I heard loading SAP on an External would make it extremely slow. I'll be using it only as a beginer so even if it is a little slow i don't mind. Is it feasible to run such a big application from an External Hard disk ?

So can i purchase a 500 or 1 TB Internal Hard disk and use it as an External too by fitting it with the necessary USB 3.0 Hard drive cases and cables ? or should i purchase a External and load SAP onto it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A general statement like "loading SAP on an External HD would make it extremely slow" is pure, uninformed FUD. For an installation running on a notebook, the main determinant will be RAM size. Get as much as you can :-) and fit the system in there without making it page. Use perfmon to check. The default values used by MiniSAP (or Testdrive on Linux) are pretty good.